# Етимологічний зв’язок слів бачити та про(ви)бач

Tags: вживання-слів, етимологія

Чи однокоріневі слова *бачити* та *пробач / вибач*?
Якщо вони не однокоріневі -- то коли змінилося значення одного зі слів, і при яких обставинах?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Однокоріневі в будь-якому сенсі, в тому числі й в етимологічному сенсі.

> <sup>[Етимологічний словник української мови в семи томах, том 1: 154–155 сторінки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)</sup>
>
> **бачити**, *бачця* «здається», [*бача*] «видіння» (*Пискунов Ф.*, Словарь живого народного, письменного и актового языка русских южан. Изд. 2-у К., 1882) *бачність* «обережність», *бачний* «обережний», [*бачливий*] «*так само*; уважний» (*Желехівський Є.*, Недільський С. Малорусько-німецький словар. Т. 1–2. Львів, 1886), [*бачучий*] «зіркий», [*бачущий*] «*так само*», *вибачати* «прощати», ***вибачити*** «пробачити; [роздивитись, розгледіти (*Курило 0.* Матеріали до украхнськох діалектологія та фольклристики. К., 1928.)]», [*збачати*] «прощати; помічати», *завбачити*, *завбачливий*, [*знебачки*] «несподівано», [*знебашки*, *знеобачка*] «*так само*», [*зобачити*] «попробувати» (*Курило 0.* Матеріали до украхнськох діалектологія та фольклристики. К., 1928.), [*навбач*] «на вигляд», *недобачати*, [*недобачливий*] «з поганим зором», [*недобачний*] «невидимий, неоглядний» (*Желехівський Є*., Недільський С. Малорусько-німецький словар. Т. 1–2. Львів, 1886), [*необачка*] «безпечність, нерозсудливість», [*необачки*] «несподівано» (*Желехівський Є.*, Недільський С. Малорусько-німецький словар. Т. 1–2. Львів, 1886), *обачити* «побачити, помітити», [*обачитися*] «видужати», *обачний* «обережний», *обачливий* «*так само*», [*перебачати*] «прощати» (*Желехівський Є.*, Недільський С. Малорусько-німецький словар. Т. 1–2. Львів, 1886), *передбачати*, *передбачливий*, *побачення*, ***пробачати*** «прощати», *пробачення*, *пробачливий*, [*убачливий*] «уважний», *старе* *бачити* «пильнувати» (1436); — *московська* [*бачить*] «бачити», *білоруська* *бачыць*, *польська* baczyć «звертати увагу, зважати; (*старе*) бачити», *чеська* [přebačić] «не помітити», *словацька* [báčiť] «дивитися»;
>
> більшість дослідників (Bern. I 23—24; Фасмер І 138; Шанский ЭСРЯ І 2, 61–62; Richhardt 32; Sławski I 24; Sł. prasł. I 174—175) вважає запозиченням з польської мови, в якій пояснюється як результат перерозкладу префіксального дієслова *ob-ačiti, повʼязаного, нібито, з іменником *oko;
>
> *польська* baczyć виводилось також від іменника *baki «очі» (Brückner 10), від гіпотетичного *bakъ «сторож, наглядач, опікун» (Baudouin de Courtenay Szkice 438–439), від вигуку здивування ba (Leht-Spławiński JP 26, 166–170), від patrzyć «дивитись» (Machek ESJČ 425), а також від *іранська* *abi-āxšaya- «бачити, спостерігати, оберігати, памʼятати» (Трубачев Этимология 1965, 43–47);
>
> не може бути категорично відкинуте і припущення (Matzenauer LF 1, 4) про запозичення з турецької мови, в якій дієслівна основа bak- «дивитись, турбуватись, звертати увагу, бути обережним» і *так далі* є спільнотюркською

Comment: Ще посилання про етимологію слова «бачити»: [цитати з 4 етимологічних словників у обговоренні спільноти ru_etymology у livejournal](//ru-etymology.livejournal.com/1345051.html?thread=26914331#t26914331), [обговорення на «Лингвофорум»](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=19544.0), [дві цікаві виноски в українській Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Полонізм#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D0.B9.D0.B1.D1.96.D0.BB.D1.8C.D1.88_.D1.83.D0.B6.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.96_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BD.D1.96.D0.B7.D0.BC.D0.B8).